# Probability of extinction

Tags: probability, statistics

Rare animals in a game reserve are found to give birth to new ones at the rate of 6 in 2 years and to die at the rate of 0.25 a month.

What is the probability of extinction after 4 months...

> (i) ...if there were only three animals at the beginning?
>
> (ii) ...if there was only one animal at the beginning?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Comment: For ii) can we use the facts of biology to override the given data?  What is your assumption of the distribution.  Presumably the death rate is an exponential decay-a chance of 0.25 that each animal dies each month.  How are the births distributed?